# Is it possible that Azure Service Bus created a duplicate of the message?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We have experienced some strange behavior with Azure Service Bus that we could not figure out how to explain other than some bug in Azure. This is what happened:

1. We have sent a message to the Azure Service Bus one time
2. The call to send message took a bit longer than one minute to execute but succeeded nonetheless and message was received fine after that
3. A duplicate message has appeared with `EnqueuedTimeUtc` about half a second later and `SequenceNumber` that is different from the first message but it had the same content and `MessageId` that we generated

Now we are fairly sure we have only made one call to `SendMessage` since we do log right before that and we log all the received messages as well.

We also do not think that this is the client library that does that because between these two messages that appeared on the bus there were other messages sent and I don't think that client library does this on the background while allowing others to go through. Not 100% sure of this though. Here is what we figured out happened:

1. First message is sent
2. It takes ~63 seconds for the operation to be completed
3. Some other messages are sent after that
4. About 30 seconds after the first message is sent a duplicate appears (according to EnqueuedTime at least).

So the question is: has someone experienced something similar and can it be a bug/temporal problems with the Azure itself, do they have any guarantees against that this won't happen? Since the call took over one minute I suspect there was something going in Azure at that time that maybe could have caused it (update e.g. or something like that)

Comment: I'm not entirely sold on the hypothesis of client side retry mechanism duplicating your messages. **1**) Could you share a repro code (GitHub or similar)? **2**) Have you raised an issue with the client team to validate this scenario?

Comment: @SeanFeldman I am not entirely sure what you mean, since I actually doubt that this was the client library (or you mean it was the library?). I cannot unfortunately reproduce the issue because it happened only once out of some few hundred thousands messages and the code really is nothing but a loop with .Send() on a list of messages. Not sure you can extract anything useful there, but I can try to find out a refined example. As for the scenario, no I have not raised an issue, do you mean a scenario when it takes that long for the message to be sent? I have expanded a bit the answer

Comment: that's what I meant, that it's not client library issue. What I meant by raising an issue is verifying with ASB team. To be fair, best option would be to investigate with Azure support as they can see internal logs. Given it was not so recently, it would be difficult to achieve now. I have not seen this behaviour.

Comment: Do you know how long are the logs they have? It's about 2 weeks now, so we'll probably have to wait and see if it happens again and then notify them at once to see what happened.

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I would still try to ping to see if that's something they still have.

Comment: @SeanFeldman Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: I know I am late to this party! Even I see the same observation when we were testing and simulating transient network issues by disconnecting/reconnecting the internet while the .Net SDK client application is sending messages in batches to the queue. We observed that there were extra messages delivered which didnt corroborate with our logs. Our logs indicated that it sent only 15,000 messages but the ASB portal count showed 15,021 !
Are there new insights into this from anyone?

@SeanFeldman

Comment: The remote nature of the service doesn't exclude the possibility there will be 100% guarantee on delivery. Therefore, as pointed out in [one of the answers below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837275/59563), there's a chance for sending the message successfully but not receiving the acknowledgement, resulting in a retry. You could verify that by investigating your messages and identifying the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen and it's kind of "normal". Service Bus SDK has internal auto-retry policy to overcome transient errors. So, if the first try succeeds but response got lost due to a network issue, it will try again and effectively will deliver the message twice.

> It is possible for an error at the client or network level to occur a moment earlier, and for a sent message to be committed into the queue, with the acknowledgment not successfully returned to the client. This scenario leaves the client in doubt about the outcome of the send operation.

To fight this issue, you can enable [Duplicate Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection) with some interval. This will prevent duplicate Message IDs to be send within such interval.

There is a drawback:

> Note that enabling duplicate detection and the size of the window directly impact the queue (and topic) throughput, since all recorded message-ids must be matched against the newly submitted message identifier.

Ideally, you would have idempotent receiver, which means it's prepared for duplicates. But this is not always possible / convenient.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have idempotent receiver but it's unfortunately not possible because we use API to Firebase that isn't any idempotent at all. Do you mean that there could have been client library that tried to send two times? We have thought of that and this probably isn't the case because other messages were sent in between. I have expanded the question with more details.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Same client can send multiple messages in parallel from different threads, depending on your messaging channel factory configuration. The one starter later could complete earlier.

Comment: We have just one thread that sends messages. I meant that it can't happen that `SendMessage` succeeds while there is some retry in the background in the same thread?

Comment: That's what we think as well, so it does not look like this happened because of the client library itself, but rather Azure on the server side. Though of course it's quite hard to detect 100% and this happened like once out of few hundred thousands messages.

Comment: Service Bus is a distributed system, so I think the same principle applies regardless. If you need guarantees, use the features that provide them, and otherwise be prepared to anomalies.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer :) I assume we cannot really expect 100% guarantee anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think your message sending application has encountered some error or delay while sending a message to the Service Bus messaging entity.So it has retried sending the same message with same message Id but with a different sequence number.

Azure Service Bus avails us the **Duplicate Detection** property to prevent the reception of duplicate copies of the messages within the queue i.e the messages with same Message Ids. When you enable the duplicate detection property of the queue by setting the duplicate detection time history with a predefined time interval, only a single message with same message Id will be available in the queue and the messages with duplicate message Id's will be lost.

You can avoid your problem by using the duplicate detection property and you can also send a message with customized message Id to the Service Bus Queue or Topic.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Yes, we know of duplication detection and it was not on at the time this happened. As for the delay and resend, so I highly doubt it since there were other messages sent in between first and second occurrence of the message with same ID, though of course I am not sure of how exactly the client library does it.